# Split after n words Power BI

Tags: split, powerbi

I have this in PowerBI : [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wx7h.png)
And I would like to split the data after the 2 first words.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the result you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating these two custom columns in the Query Editor:

Left Text: `Text.BeforeDelimiter([Colonne 2], " ", 1)`

Right Text: `Text.AfterDelimiter([Colonne 2], " ", 1)`

This searches for the second space (the index starts at 0) in `Colonne 2` and gives you the part before or the part after.